# I'm trying to get a list of all Drivers on my system WITH their version details. Windows 11

Tags: drivers, windows-11

I'm preparing to Clean-Install Windows 11. I want to get a list of all my Drivers I have currently installed so that I can compare it with a second list I would make after doing the re-installation, so that I can be sure I haven't missed any Drivers in that re-installation. I know that

`driverquery/v`

in Command Prompt will give me the names of the drivers. This Power Shell command

`Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | select devicename, driverversion`

, which I read somewhere is what someone on Windows 7 would run for this, does actually return the version details, but it seemingly only returns entries for half of the drivers; it gives a list of about 200 Drivers whereas the

`driverquery/v`

command gives details for about 400 Drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm preparing to Clean-Install Windows 11. I want to get a list of all my Drivers I have currently installed so that I can compare it with a second list I would make after doing the re-installation, so that I can be sure I haven't missed any Drivers in that re-installation.

There's an easier approach to that: **export the actual drivers** to a USB stick or somewhere.

```
dism /online /export-driver /destination:C:\OldDrivers
```

After reinstall, step 1 would be to run Windows Update so that it could install all drivers published via Microsoft (don't forget to check the "Optional" updates). For any machine that's officially supported by Windows 11 this should cover 100% of the necessary drivers; for older ones it's generally 90% or so.

Once Windows Update is done, look through Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) for any device that still seems to lack a driver, and tell it to "update" the drivers from the `OldDrivers` folder that you exported earlier.

(I found an article that suggests `pnputil /add-driver <path>\*.inf /subdirs /install` to mass-install the drivers, but I'm not sure whether that's necessary.)

Comment: @william - `driverquery/v` is printing more than the drivers that are actively used by the system. If this answer does not answer your question, you are under no obligation, to accept the answer. `dism /online /export-driver` should only export the drivers required by the system.

Answer (score 0):

You may use PowerShell to list all drivers by device and version,
by using the
[Get-WindowsDriver command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-windowsdriver?view=windowsserver2022-ps):

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select devicename, driverversion, DriverProviderName
```